# How to reverse animation when prop is false styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am passing a open prop to styled component to create animations for the hamburger icon.
This is the code

```
const StyledBurger = styled.button`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 0;
  background-color: ${colors.cobaltBlue};
  border-radius: 2.7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  div {
    width: 27px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 1.5px;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    border-radius: 1.4px;
    background-color: ${colors.white};
    :first-child {
      ${({ open }) => open && firstOpenAnimation};
    }
    :nth-child(2) {
      opacity: ${({ open }) => (open ? '0' : '1')};
    }
    :nth-child(3) {
      ${({ open }) => open && seconOpenAnimation}
    }
  }
`;

const firstOpenKeyframe = keyframes`
  50% {
    transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(6px) rotate(45deg);
  }
`;

const secondOpenKeyframe = keyframes`
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
`;

const firstCloseKeyFrame = keyframes`
  50% {
    transform:translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform:translateY(-6px) rotate(-45deg)  ;
  }
`;

const firstOpenAnimation = css`
  animation: 0.3s linear ${firstOpenKeyframe} forwards;
`;

const seconOpenAnimation = css`
  animation: 0.3s linear ${secondOpenKeyframe} forwards;
`;

const firstCloseAnimation = css`
  animation: 0.3s linear ${firstCloseKeyFrame} forwards;
`;

export default StyledBurger;
```

Basically what I want is if the menu is not open to reverse the animation that was created after the first click.
I tried doing a conditional render of animation keyframe based on the prop open but what happens is when the page loads it immediately creates the animation of not is opened because it satisfies false.
What can I do to fix this and create the opposite animation when unClicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make few corrections and it should all work properly.

- use state to toggle open and send it as prop to your styled component
- use ternary for animation (not just &&) `${({ open }) => (open ? firstOpenAnimation : firstCloseAnimation)}`.
- implement missing close second animation

[working copy of your code is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-css-animation-fix-wf1e1?file=/src/App.js)

**Working code snippet**

```js
const StyledBurger = styled.button`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 0;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 2.7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
  div {
    width: 27px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 1.5px;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    border-radius: 1.4px;
    background-color: white;
    :first-child {
      ${({ open }) =>
        open !== null && (open ? firstOpenAnimation : firstCloseAnimation)}
    }
    :nth-child(2) {
      opacity: ${({ open }) => (open ? "0" : "1")};
    }
    :nth-child(3) {
      ${({ open }) =>
        open !== null && (open ? seconOpenAnimation : secondCloseAnimation)}
    }
  }
`;

const firstOpenKeyframe = keyframes`
  50% {
    transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(6px) rotate(45deg);
  }
`;

const secondOpenKeyframe = keyframes`
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
`;

const firstCloseKeyFrame = keyframes`
  50% {
    transform:translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform:translateY(0) rotate(0)  ;
  }
`;
const secondCloseKeyFrame = keyframes`
  50% {
    transform:translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform:translateY(0) rotate(0)  ;
  }
`;

const firstOpenAnimation = css`
  animation: 0.3s linear ${firstOpenKeyframe} forwards;
`;

const seconOpenAnimation = css`
  animation: 0.3s linear ${secondOpenKeyframe} forwards;
`;
const secondCloseAnimation = css`
  animation: 0.3s linear ${secondCloseKeyFrame} forwards;
`;

const firstCloseAnimation = css`
  animation: 0.3s linear ${firstCloseKeyFrame} forwards;
`;
export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <StyledBurger onClick={() => setOpen(prev => !prev)} open={open}>
        <div />
        <div />
        <div />
      </StyledBurger>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This still does the firstCloseAnimation on render

Comment: ok - just have the initial state of `open` as `false` .. like this `const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);` ... i have updated the answer as well as the code in the sandbox...

Comment: Thanks for your time, but still from the sandbox if you refresh it youll see the animation taking place, this is because we are sending a conditional to styled components thats either true or false and at false it renders an animation

Comment: i see what you mean .... ok - keep initial state as null and then don't do animation if null ... else do the usual ternary .... i have updated the answer as well as sandbox(refresh it) .... let me know if not it is not working

Comment: This worked perfectly, now I am trying to create the exact opposite when unclicked i am not able to achieve it

Comment: awesome :) ... okay - i guess your main issue is solved ... you can pls consider to accept the answer... thanks.

Comment: Done, can you also help with the animation?  something like this https://codepen.io/husnimun/pen/pJvEeL